# PropertyEditor databinder in Spring 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am reading the [Validator part in Spring3 Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.13.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#validation) where the `PropertyEditor` `DataBinder`  `ConversionService` `Formatter` are introduced.

IMO, these components are used for converting object to string and string to object,  for example, in a Spring Web application, the http requests parameters may be parsed and assembled to a form object like this:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/user", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addUser(User user) { /* ... */ }
}
```

With html:

```
<form>
  <input name="user.name" />
  <input name="user.email" />
</form>
```

Where the `user` object should be auto created and filled with properties from the http form.

But I am confused with the `PropertyEditor` `DataBinder`  `ConversionService` `Formatter` concepts.

Is there a clear explanation?

Answer (score 1):

`PropertyEditor` is part of the JDK. It was intended for forms in desktop applications and is more than a simple converter. It's supported by Spring, but I don't recommend it.

A `Formatter` is a specialized `String` <-> other type converter. It is used when a type can be represented as a string in a variety of formats (sic!). Dates for example.

Arbitrary type conversions are mostly accomplished by a `Converter` or a `GenericConverter`.

A `ConversionService` is a service that calls converters, formatters etc. You usually don't implement one yourself, but simply register your own converters.

The `DataBinder` is the component that manages the whole process. Before a controller method is called Spring creates a `DataBinder` and calls its `bind` method. The binder calls the necessary conversion services which in turn call the converters.